# Powershell custom prompt with posh-git git status prompt

Tags: powershell, git, prompt, windows-terminal, profile

I made my own custom prompt for PowerShell and my prompt be look like :
`[HH:mm] omkrbhagat C:\Users\onkar ~`

Then, I installed `posh-git` module and import in my profile.
Auto tab completion for git commands are working well but I can't see git status prompt. Then I came to know that if I have my own custom prompt then git status prompt can't consolidate with custom prompt. For this I need to use `& $GitPromptScriptBlock`. Can you show me how to achieve that and along with that I want git status prompt only when I initialize the git repository.

This is my own custom prompt for pwsh :

```
function prompt {
    $time = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
    $location = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).Path

    $promptText = "["
    $promptText += "$([char]27)[96m$time$([char]27)[0m "
    $promptText += "$([char]27)[32momkrbhagat$([char]27)[0m "
    $promptText += "$([char]27)[35m$location$([char]27)[0m"

    $promptText += " $(Write-VcsStatus -NoColor) "  # Add Git status prompt

    Write-Host $promptText -NoNewline
    return " ~ "
}
```

Comment: Hello, what is the specific question here? You know what var to add to the prompt, you got the prompt function. Is something not working or do you not know how to append the variable?

Comment: @Destroy666 it does work in GIT.

Comment: @RohitGupta I have no idea what you mean and how that answers my comments.

Comment: @Destroy666 I mean that when I initialize the git repository, only then I want to see  the posh-git Git status prompt. It can be achieve using `if-else` but I don't know how exactly I can do that.

Comment: What does it show in non-repository directories?

Comment: @ Destroy666 in a non repository directory it shows posh-git status prompt